# sqldf error in R

Tags: java, mysql, r, jdbc

I just formatted my laptop & post that, I have been getting this error.
And I have run this code many times before without any issues. 
How do I fix this issue?

I have the following libraries installed.

```
library(sqldf)
library(RH2)
library(dplyr)
library(RJDBC)
library(RODBC)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
```

And I have Java 8 & Java SE 8 running as well.

**Code**

```
chk1 <- sqldf("select month, count(*) as n_rows, sum(revenue) as rev, sum(billable_units) as tonnes
+               from rev_bulk_fy13
+               group by 1")

Loading required package: tcltk

Error in .verify.JDBC.result(s, "Unable to execute JDBC statement ", statement) : 
  Unable to execute JDBC statement select month, count(*) as n_rows, sum(revenue) as rev, sum(billable_units) as tonnes
              from rev_bulk_fy13
              group by 1 (Column "billable_units" not found; SQL statement:
select month, count(*) as n_rows, sum(revenue) as rev, sum(billable_units) as tonnes
              from rev_bulk_fy13
              group by 1 [42122-175])
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `group by month` ?

Comment: Well, is there a column `billable_units` in `rev_bulk_fy13`?? Have you checked??

Comment: (1) As Abhik already mentioned, H2 does not support the `group by` number syntax.  (SQLite does support that syntax.) (2) Also note that it would be good enough to issue these two `library` calls: `library(RH2); library(sqldf)`.  The others would be pulled in anyways. (3) Next time please make your example reproducible by including some sample data.